# Usage/meaning of "brattery"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Looking for translations of room for children I found the word "brattery" along with the word "nursery", which I believe is most commonly used for children's room in a house. Is "brattery" still in use or is it obsolete now? Or does it have some specific context?

Comment: Whereever did you find that translation? It must have been an old book indeed. *Brattery* enjoyed [some currency in the 1840s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brattery&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrattery%3B%2Cc0) and was even [included in early dictionaries](http://books.google.com/books?id=IyFpRqyIQuYC&pg=RA1-PA69&dq=%22brattery%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aPddVKfUA4fjsATS24K4Dw&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCQ) but hasn't seen the light of day in a long time.

Comment: I don't think it ever really saw much use; it is a humorous combination of *nursery* and *brat*.

Comment: I imagine, even when it was in use, it was a tongue-in-cheek derivation of the word [*brat*](http://i.word.com/idictionary/brat) which means ill-behaved or annoying child. Hence *brattery* meant all of a family's ill-behaved or annoying children. (if you click through the NGrams' citations of the word, you'll find it frequently co-locates with *squalling* etc).

Comment: Russian to English dictionary, it was mentioned when I look for "children's" translation. As I newer saw/heard this one before it sparked my interest. And the same dictionary which gave me this word doesn't have an article/entry for "brattery"... So I see it is kind of stuff you can find in OED or something similar only :)

Comment: @Peter, it actually meant the children themselves, not the room they lived in.

Comment: @Dan: looking at Google books, it was used for both the children and for the room. For example, *"but, alas ! the apartment above my head proves a squalling brattery,"*

Comment: 100 years from now, the same question will turn up about "rugrat".

Comment: You can look at Google n-grams to get an idea of how its usage has changed over time: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brattery&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrattery%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

*Brat* is a word originating c.1500, slang meaning *beggar's child* (Etymonline)

According to [Encyclo.Co.UK](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/define/Brattery), a *brattery* is British slang for a nursery, a creche, a school.

[A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](http://books.google.com/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=define+brattery&source=bl&ots=_2KBiKlN0K&sig=b4SZZzikzeOhjM-u3A1UCBGlWRI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RQ9eVPqiBoSryQScq4KADA&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=define%20brattery&f=false) lists its use from c. 1780 as a pejorative colloquialism for *nursery*

> The apartment above my head proves a squalling brattery. - Beckford, 1834

A recent use:

> In a recent display of full-blown *brattery*, several liberal operatives renewed attacks on me at another website. - The BulletProof Monk

Though I've never heard it, seeing as brat and rug rat are common names for small children, I think it's meaning is easy to arrive at.

Comment: It's slightly common to add "-ery" to other words, as a humorous device. I think in both AmE and BrE.

Answer (score 2):

If you saw it used recently, it's simply **a humorous addition** of "-ery" to the word "brat".

Note that we have common ("real") words like nunnery, fishery and so on.

It's somewhat common to do **the same thing to other words** - for humorous effect.

So, say you refer to your buddies as "wankers", you might walk in and say "what's happening in this **wankery** today!" ... ok?

It's just possible that the word, in the distant past, existed and was used: but it does not today.

(1) It is "not a word", do not use it ever.

(2) Adding "-ery" is a somewhat common sort of language humour. That's what you saw, if you saw or heard a recent usage.

---

Note - you have mentioned in a comment (why not edit the question?) this is from a Russian to English dictionary.  Forget it, the dictionary is crap.

That's all there is to it.

---

Just to be perfectly clear Mikhail, if you don't know, "brat" is simply current aggressive slang for "badly behaved kid".  (Don't use it when talking normally; only use it when screaming or about to get in a fight. Example "Control that brat of yours!")

It's about the same tone as calling an adult an "idiot".

Comment: I'd say this suffix is still "productive" everywhere, but it often has significant AmE overtones to me *(nuttery = mental hospital, eatery = eating-house, etc.)*. I've no idea why you can put your cat in a ***cattery*** while you're away on holiday, but there's no equivalent ***doggery***.

Comment: I would ... suspect that say "eatery" is pretty old. I *think* the only way it is productive, in AmE today, is just humorously / sarcastically.  BTW I believe "doggery" specifically has another meaning; it's fairly common right? I think that's precisely why it's not used in the "cattery" sense.

Comment: *Doggery* isn't/wasn't known to me. The first definition I just found was M-W [*a cheap saloon*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doggery) (presumably, AmE only). And [*doglike behavior or conduct, especially when surly*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/doggery), which is what I'd call *doggishness* (or *dogginess* if I'm being "cute"). I don't specifically recall even *hearing* it before, but I wouldn't be surprised to learn I've used [*fuckuppery*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fuckuppery) more than once. Prolly it's just throwaway nonce-words these days.